# simplehtmldom URL extraction and matching for pattern

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have following code which extracts all the hyperlinks(urls) from the given web url.

```
<?php include "simple_html_dom.php";

$html=new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://www.indiastudychannel.com/colleges');
$links=$html->find('a');

foreach($links as $l)
{

    $path='http://www.indiastudychannel.com/colleges'.$l->href;
    //doScrape($path);
    echo $path."<br>";
}
?>
```

The above code extracts all the hyperlinks but I want to extract only links which has following pattern.

http://www.indiastudychannel.com/colleges/54499-Godavari-College-Nursing.aspx
http://www.indiastudychannel.com/colleges/54489-Rvs-College-Arts-And-Science.aspx
http://www.indiastudychannel.com/colleges/54488-Sankara-Institute-Management.aspx

I know that this can be done using regular expressions but how exactly that I don't know. Please give example so I can easily understand.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
preg_match("/^http://www.indiastudychannel.com/colleges/54489/\");
```

take a look at

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

and

http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php